# Replace Text in Spark Dataframe

Tags: regex, scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to process the XML file by using `databrics` library. In that case, there are some special characters like  `&#x2018;`. After writing to csv file the text looks like `â€˜`. For this i tried following ways:

1. By using Translate:

```
df.select($"column",translate($"column","T","A").as("new_column")).show()
```

2. By using regex:

```
df.withColumn("column", concat_ws(",",$"column".cast(sql.types.StringType)))
  .select($"column",regexp_replace($"column","&#x2018;","AP").as("column"))
```

In the above two cases, I didn't get proper output. it returns again `â€˜`.

Is there any way to get the text as it is?

```
input : Nectarine tree named &#x2018;Polar Zee&#x2019;

current Output: Nectarine tree named â€˜Polar Zeeâ€™

expected Output : Nectarine tree named &#x2018;Polar Zee&#x2019;
```

Comment: it looks like encoding problem.

Comment: How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: when you are creating dataframe try option like .option("charset","UTF-8") with appropriate encoding.